# Help with this simple theorem related to the Wald test

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm studying the book [all statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441923225) by Wasserman and I'm trying to prove the theorem following the definition of the Wald Test on page 153.

> **10.3 Definition.** The Wald Test
>
> Consider testing
>
> $H_0:\theta = \theta_0\ \text{versus}\ H_1 : \theta = \theta_ 0$
>
> **If $H_0$ is true**, assume that $\hat{\theta}\ \text{is asymptotically Normal:}$
>
> $\frac{\hat\theta-\theta_0}{\hat {se}}\xrightarrow{(d)} \mathcal
>  N(0,1)$
>
> The size $\alpha$ Wald test is: reject $H_0$ when
> $|W|>z_{\alpha/2}$ where
>
> $W=\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta_0}{\hat{se}}$

Now he states this theorem, but without prove it:

> **10.6 Theorem.**
>
> Suppose the true value of $\theta$ is $\theta_* \neq \theta_0$ . The
> power $\beta(\theta_*)$ — the probability of correctly rejecting the
> null hypothesis — is given (approximately) by
>
> $$1 - \Phi\bigg(\frac{\theta_0-\theta_*}{\hat{se}}+z_{\alpha/2}\bigg)
> + \Phi\bigg(\frac{\theta_0-\theta_*}{\hat{se}}-z_{\alpha/2}\bigg)$$

---

**My Attempt to prove the theorem**

Suppose the true value of $\theta$ is $\theta_*$ and I want to know

$$\beta(\theta_*)=\mathbb P_{\theta_*}\bigg(\frac{|\theta_*-\theta_0|}{\hat{se}}>z_{\alpha/2}\bigg)=\mathbb P_{\theta_*}\bigg(\frac{\theta_*-\theta_0}{\hat{se}}>z_{\alpha/2}\bigg)+\mathbb P_{\theta_*}\bigg(\frac{\theta_*-\theta_0}{\hat{se}}<-z_{\alpha/2}\bigg)$$

How can I proceed from there? am I right so far?

---

**A definition you may need:**

> If $\mathcal F = \{ f(x; \theta) : \theta \in \Theta \}$ is a
> parametric model, we write $P_{\theta}(X\in A) = \int_A f(x;
>  \theta)dx$. The subscript $\theta$ indicates that the probability is
> with respect to $f(x;\theta)$.

Comment: Please refer to the answer posted here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390673/derive-a-hypothesis-test-z/1391096#1391096  as well as here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478667/proof-of-the-power-of-the-wald-test

Comment: @heropup Exactly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @heropup in this answer, he uses the asymptotic normality, $\frac{\hat{\theta} - \theta_0}{\hat{se}} \sim N(0,1)$. However this is only true, if $H_0$ is true, no? please see my recent question about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967313/not-clear-definition-in-wasserman-book

Comment: Under the alternative hypothesis, the test statistic is still asymptotically normally distributed; it simply has a different mean.

Comment: @heropup, haa ok, that makes a lot of sense now, so my add to Wasserman's definition is wrong in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967313/not-clear-definition-in-wasserman-book?

Comment: Just for future reference, this answer is also helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2677980/42912